# Import data from web query

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a pre-built Excel sheet that has a data link so whenever I click 'refresh data' it pulls in all the data from a web query. I am pretty unfamiliar with data links but would like to convert it to a Google Sheets. Looking around the Excel documentation the only link I can find to look at where to get the data from is [this](https://myflightbook.com/logbook/public/export.aspx?user=[%22User%22,%22Enter%20your%20MyFlightBook%20email%20address:%22]&pass=[%22Pass%22,%22Enter%20your%20MyFlightBook%20password:%22]).

Is there a way to link that data into Google Docs to automatically update?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks lime `ImportHTML` does the trick. Now on to the task of figuring out how to make that function auto-update. So if anyone has any insight on making that function refresh automatically that would be greatly appreciated.